# Java: calling join() multiple times on same thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have threads A, B and C. I'm starting A and B simultaneously and thread C will execute it's logic after A and B end. I also want to do other operations after A ends and different operations after thread B ends.

So I designed it this way:

```
final Thread a = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something
    }
};

final Thread b = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something
    }
};

AbstractAction x = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        a.start();
        try {
            a.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        }

        // do some other things
    }
};

AbstractAction y = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        b.start();
        try {
            b.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        }

        // do some more different things
    }
};

Thread c = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            a.join();
            b.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        // do things after a and b ends
    }
};
```

I'm worried that I'm doing something wrong here, as I couldn't find any tips about calling join() multiple times on same thread.

On the other hand, I have no idea how can I achieve what I wand in other way. I could probably just use

```
while (a.isAlive() || b.isAlive()) {
    // do nothing
}
// do things after a and b ends
```

but for me it looks worse.

----- UPDATE 1 -----

If you asking why at all do such things...

There are two buttons b1 and b2.

x.performAction() shows indicator on b1 while in the background I'm loading data from DB (it's done in Thread a).
y.performAction() makes similar thing for b2 but loads different portion of data (Thread b).

Putting start() and join() in actionPerformed() causes showing indicator as long as data is loading. When data loading is finished, indicator disappears.

There is also other action. Before data loading is finished, button is disabled (user can't click it).

The point is to enable both buttons (letting the user to click them) only after both portions of data is loaded from DB. The point is also to allow showing indicators separately - if Thread a finishes before Thread b, there is no point for showing indicator on button b1.

Comment: So I got answer to asked question so now I see, I have to ask them more precisely :) . Maybe next time will be more lucky. I just wanted to know if this is good design, or maybe I should try more accurate Java threading features. But knowing that it's safe is also very helpful.

Comment: What is the point of starting a thread and then join()ing it on the very next line?  Your `actionPerformed()` methods might just as well call a.run() and b.run() and avoid the overhead of creating and destroying threads.

Comment: @jameslarge I'm doing it this way, because I can't find a better one to achieve what I'm doing with Thread c. And that's the point! If you see a bad design and know how to make it better, I'm still waiting for such comments :) .

Comment: I would use two flags, and one condition variable:  Each of the `actionPerformed()` methods would set one of the flags and then `notify()` the condition variable.  The thread C would `wait()` on the condition variable until both of the flags are set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the JavaDoc on [join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long%29)

> ... uses a loop of `this.wait` calls conditioned on `this.isAlive`.

so it **is** safe to call `join` as many times as you like - a dead thread will always have `false` for `isAlive`.

It is also [not](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) possible to resurrect a thread.

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

Answer (score 3):

Consider what can happen with this code:

```
a.join();
b.join();
proceed();
```

1. Both threads may be dead—proceed immediately;
2. `a` dead, `b` alive: block on second line until `b` dead;
3. `a` alive, `b` dead: block on first line until `a` dead;
4. both alive: block on first line until `a` dead, then block as needed until `b` dead.

All four cases share the following invariant:

`proceed()` is reached *as soon as*, but *no sooner than*, both `a` and `b` are dead.

Comment: And that's exactly what I wanted to achieve (and achieved) :)

Comment: So... it would seem that this answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to join multiple times on a thread

Also i noticed something not quite right if you want this code to do nothing while BOTH threads are alive why not just

```
while (!a.isAlive() && !b.isAlive()) {
    // do things
    break;
}
```

That just makes more sense to me than creating a loop to do nothing

EDIT: add a break so the loop with stop after executing once

Comment: Wouldn't that end in repeating '// do things' as long as both threads are working? I want to '// do things' only once.

Comment: It would also fail to do things at all if any thread is still alive.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Actually that's the purpose of my code - wait until both threads are dead and then do other things. It's GUI related...

Comment: @Druedain Exactly, and the effect of code in this answer is to check once and do nothing if threads are still alive. No waiting and no retrying.